# How to use setInterval document wide

Tags: android, setinterval

I'm building an android app using cordova and using gooogle admob with it, I want to show interstitial ad every 5 minutes, so I use setInterval.

I have many pages in my app. My problem is that the timer restarts every time I visit a new page.

I want to have the effect of the timer over my whole document so that it does not matter on which page the user is, I want to call the display Ad function every 5 minutes.